# android ad-hoc udp broadcast hangs on send(ndk)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, udp

I'm trying to send a broadcast message in my ad-hoc network - 192.168.2.x, using native c code.
But the app hangs on  sendto(). btw the hang is not connected to the while, that wraps it, as I can see in debug, it only tries sendto() ones and hangs.
Is there something wrong with my code?

```
int broadcast(char* msg){
    int bcast_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; // connector's address information
    if((bcast_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        LOGE("ERROR BROADCASTING , socket wasn't created");
    }

    int broadcastEnable=1;
    int ret=setsockopt(bcast_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcastEnable, sizeof(broadcastEnable));
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        LOGE("ERROR BROADCASTING, Coulnt set broadcast enable through socket options");
    }


    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     // host byte order
    their_addr.sin_port = htons(BROADCAST_PORT); // short, network byte order
    their_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
    memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

    while(-1 == (int)sendto(bcast_sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)));
    return 0;
}
```

A couple of notes:

- This of course are rooted phones.
- If I broadcast using java broadcast, it works fine, I'm able to receive the broadcast ie:

  ```
  datagramSocket.setBroadcast(true);
  int receiverPort = 4949;
  sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, receiverPort);
  ```
- Non broadcast messages are also being sent and received using native code.
- The CPU usage becomes ~ 95% .
- I've also tried simply sending to 192.168.2.255.

any ideas?

Comment: First point: their_addr should be zero'ed entirely first, and then the individual members are set. This guarantees than any hidden/forgotten member is zero.

Then, this tight loop is poor practice. Of course it will convert your phone in a heater in case of failure. A simple sleep(1) in the loop would be better.

Check the errno value (or strerror() message) within the loop to see exactly what is the error.

Comment: I added sleep, and errno is 101 - network unreachable.
Why should the broadcast be unreachable if a regular message is reachable?

Comment: Saw another thing now: you didn't bind to any interface or port, so your UDP packet does not have a source port. Try to bind to a specific NIC and UDP port. If it works, you can try to bind to INADDR_ANY (all interfaces) to see if the undirected broadcast can go to all interfaces. Directed broadcast (192.168.2.255) should work. I don't have my Stevens UNPv1 here, I don't remember if binding to INADDR_ANY and sending INADDR_BROADCAST sends to all interfaces or to only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing address conversion from:

```
their_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
```

to

```
inet_aton(IP,&their_addr.sin_addr);
```

where `IP = "192.168.2.1"`

Thanks for the help epx